# How to install Memcached on Xampp Mac

Tags: php, macos, terminal, memcached

I need to use Memcached in XAMPP because I need to develop locally, and all solutions i've seen so far, dont work.

```html
Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_memcached_driver.php on line 108
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Class 'Memcached' not found

Filename: drivers/Session_memcached_driver.php

Line Number: 108

Backtrace:


//does not work, and actually i need this not the bottom one.
//keep in mind that the service is running, and everything was succesfully
//installed with brew

$this->_memcached = new Memcached();


//works
$this->_memcached = new Memcache;
```

Comment: for OSX -> go download MAMP / MAMP PRO :)

Comment: same thing... does not work.. I've already tried that :)

Comment: Change the ports, can't imagine there is something else you could do to mess up mamp ;pp

Comment: memcache works perfectly in Xampp, but I need to use "Memcached", because the framework I am using, uses only this, and this way I can upgrade my APP in terms of performance. I already installed everything with brew, and its good, and the service is running too, but does not work in XAMPP, or MAMP or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution :)

```html
brew install libevent
brew install autoconf
brew install libmemcached

//Download the PHP version you are using and past it to:
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.7/include/php

//Configure the source with
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.7/include/php/configure

//go to
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.7/bin

//compile memcached
./pecl install memcached

//go back
cd ../

//Add the memcached.so extension to your php.ini file
echo -e "\n[memcached]\nextension=memcached.so" >> conf/php.ini

//start memcached server
memcached -m 24 -p 11211 -d

//restart MAMPP and thats it!
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

1. Install libmemcached with brew:

   > brew install libmemcached
2. Install memcached with pecl:

   - > sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install memcached
   - When prompted for the libmemcached directory, press 'Enter' and the installer will automatically find it.
3. Add the memcached extension to your php.ini file:

   - > sudo vim /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
   - Add 'extension=memcached.so' to the file
4. Restart your Apache server (either use the GUI or run):

   > sudo apachectl restart
5. Start memcached with brew:

   > brew services start memcached

Created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/maorpolak/678400fef1a81f2a72da4e23948e2075) with these instructions.

Comment: If you are using PHP 5.6.36 then try `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install memcached-2.2.0` and try to install `autoconf` and `pkg-config` using brew before installing this extension.